# Where can I find libpng and libfreetype for OS X Mountain Lion, WITHOUT installing XQuartz?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion

I have symlinked two libraries - libfreetype and libpng from the /usr/local/lib/ directory and the binary I am running now displays the "to open  you need to install X11 ...". Before that it used to complain that libfreetype and libpng were not found (at /usr/local/lib).

The thing is I do not want to install XQuartz, and my binary simply needs PNG and Freetype support. Surely, these libraries wouldn't need XQuartz either.

Is there a way to obtain these binaries without installing XQuartz? Let's assume I do not have administrator access to the computer. And yes, I own it ;-) I just don't want to install system wide stuff, and so far I have managed quite well - I have a working compiler and GNU make binary running very well.

I downloaded the standalone libpng, but it seems that at least libfreetype which resides in /usr/X11/lib is a sort of placeholder which causes the mentioned dialog to display. A dummy, that is.

Comment: You *might* be asking the wrong question. Why wouldn't you want to install XQuartz in the first place? What program is it you want to run, which seems to depend on XQuartz?

Comment: That's the thing - the program is completely unrelated to XQuartz, and  does not depend on it. It only needs libpng and libfreetype.

Comment: And what is "the program"? [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) has both of these libraries.

Comment: I do not want to disclose the program exactly because it shouldn't matter. It only wants libpng and libfreetype. Homebrew is too much for me, as I only need the program myself, and I have installed it in my per-user binaries directory that's in my PATH. Everything works now, I am writing an answer right now, so that perhaps others might benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I solved the problem myself. Long suspecting that explicit dependency listings are a human construct and do not really correspond to **actual** dependency for a program to function, I decided to dig deeper and in the end ended up with the following:

I downloaded the XQuartz package from the official site, but instead of installing it, I opened it with the program called Pacifist, a [shareware] package explorer. I then extracted two files - `libfreetype.6.dylib` and `libpng.12.0.dylib`, copied them to the same directory as the program, and it worked.

Granted XQuartz is perhaps not much more than a set of libraries and a set of binaries, but I really have no need for it. When I do, I can install it, and remove the two aforementioned files, having the program instead rely on system-wide libraries having been installed by XQuartz. Until then, I am happy to live without XQuartz. I am on a Macbook Air with 64GB SSD, and I prefer the free space I have on it for my own files.